# Why are the log odds ratios not symmetric?

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio

I am confused about a simple point. Are the 95% CI's of a log odds ratios only symmetric when computed from a logistic regression? What if I got an odds ratio from a fishers exact test and converted it into a log odds ratio, does that guarantee symmetry? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: It depends: exactly what confidence interval procedure are you using??

Comment: Just a two-sided, fishers exact test for a 95% CI. I was told if I converted my odds ratio and CI's into log space, that this would be symmetric but found that wasn't the case.

Comment: That still doesn't pin it down. See the abstract at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2852239/ for an explanation of why the particular CI procedure matters.

Comment: Yeah not sure I follow. But my test is pretty significant but maybe im not grasping the abstract well enough.

Comment: I would not anticipate symmetric intervals in general. An interval for the log of an odds ratio based on the hypergeometric will not in general be symmetric (in either of the usual senses). An asymptotic interval for log-odds *might* be symmetric depending on how its obtained.